# Cannot hit breakpoints inside nested async-await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm new to asynchronous coding in C# and there's something I'm not understanding. I have the code layout as shown below. `Method1` (which is a unit test method that I manually execute) calls `Method2`, which in turn calls `Method3`, all done asynchronously. When debugging, I'm able to hit breakpoints till `Method2`, but I cannot get the debugger to hit any breakpoint inside `Method3`, and instead, focus returns back to `Method1` ... Can someone explain to me why is this happening ? How come I'm able to hit breakpoint inside `Method2` but not `Method3` ?

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Method1()
{
   ... <some code before> ... //breakpoint1 - hits!

   await Method2(...)

   ... <some code after> ... //breakpoint4 - hits immediately after hitting breakpoint2, skipping breakpoint3

}

public async Task<SampleResponseObject> Method2(...)
{
   ... <some code before> ...

   return await Method3(...); //breakpoint2 - hits! But I cannot step into this.

}

internal virtual async Task<SampleResponseObject> Method3(...)
{
   ... <some code here> ... //breakpoint3 - does NOT hit!
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example?